# git update version error: curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: certificate, git-for-windows

I try to update git version in AzureDevOps agent server by command `git update-git-for-windows`
but get an error:

```
    PS C:\Program Files\Git> git update-git-for-windows
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
PS C:\Program Files\Git> git update-git-for-windows
curl: (60) SSL certificate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
More details here: https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl failed to verify the legitimacy of the server and therefore could not
establish a secure connection to it. To learn more about this situation and
how to fix it, please visit the web page mentioned above.
```

I have a RootCA.crt in the config:

```
[user]
      name = tfsbuild
      email = tfsbuild@XXX
[http]
     sslCAInfo = C:/Users/tfsbuild/RootCA.crt
```

EDIT:
The Solution is:
add CURL_CA_BUNDLE to user variables with the special certificate.

Comment: Have you read the URL listed in the error message (https://curl.se/docs/sslcerts.html)?

Comment: Yes, I read, and the solution is to add use variable - CURL_CA_BUNDLE with my crt